# How to use indexing in laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am an indexing column to speed up the queries. before that, I had only done full-text indexing. for which I need to write special syntax. My question is there a special syntax to write a query or I can just use the where() method on that column?

Can I use it like this?

```
Model::where('customer_id',2)->get()
```

Indexing will be applied to that query?

The second thing I want to know is it will consume less MySQL server CPU ? or more?
Because I am having the issue of 100% percent CPU consumption because of lots of queries can indexing help me out with that?

The third thing is do I need to import data again after doing indexing? or it will be automatically implemented on all the Data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking a few questions here.

Indexes are applied to the database and help it make queries more efficiently. Databases are really good at what they do and will pick an "execution plan" that makes the most sense. This means it is either going to scan your table directly, or if you've setup an index that is more efficient then it will use that.

> Can I use it like this?
> Indexing will be applied to that query?

You don't have to do anything special after creating an index, your database will automatically use it on relevant queries

> The second thing I want to know is it will consume less MySQL server CPU ? or more?

In my experience, less. You are providing a way for the database to query data more efficiently and so it needs to spend less time computing what you want. Indexes do take up more *storage* though.

> The third thing is do I need to import data again after doing indexing? or it will be automatically implemented on all the Data?

It's applied automatically and you do not need to do anything special.

Comment: Great... ` Indexes do take up more storage though.` it means that hard disk memory or cpur memory?

Comment: @Bilalarshad they will take up more hard disk memory.